# Calculating ranges between 00 and 09 (not between 0 and 9)

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to test a number to be between ranges 00 and 09. I have been instructed that it must be done exactly so and not 0-9.
Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: But that is the exact same ranges.

Comment: A number is between 0-9. A string can lexically be between 00-09.

Comment: Are you trying to test if a number is between (octal) 0 and (octal) 9?
Note: That doesn't make any sense... octal is 8 based, 9 is an invalid digit.

Comment: 00 has the same value as 0, and 09 has the same value as 9.

Comment: @zdan: Right, I noted that. I accidentally commented without the note because pressing enter while typing a comment posts it, doesn't put a new line. X|

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide code that you have written so that we can comment on it -- you won't benefit from just asking other people to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 2):

Is this homework?

There is no such thing as the "number" `09`. That is a digit string, like a telephone "number". If you want to compare digit strings, plain old string comparison is all you need. E.g. `strcmp` or use `std::string`.

However, make sure you are confident what 'between` means? Define how you want to handle non-digit entries.

Comment: this is an assignment. We are to read in an ISBN number without any hashes and figure out if it's a valid ISBN.
If the user types in 0001234567, the area would be 0 and the publisher could be 00, but it's also possible the ISBN could be wrong as the publisher may be 01234567.

Comment: @Fred Put his information in your question. This will provide you with better answers for what you need. ATM your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged this as being a C/C++ question, so I figured I would add this information.  In those languages, an integer beginning with zero is an octal integer (base 8).  In base 8, there is no digit 9--only digits 0..7 are allowed.  (The decimal number 9 is 11 in base 8).

However, octal is just another way of representing numbers.  There is no difference between the decimal range from 0 to 7 or the octal range from 0 to 07.